# Generate "id" in a foreach with modal dialog in Laravel with js

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

Someone can help me with js?? I need that all the time that this foreach is executed create an "id" to open the diferents dialog modals for each posts. How i can implement my {{post->id}} in js and generate new "id" for each posts?

This all code are inside another foreach that list all the posts:

```html
<button type="button" id="btn-open-modal">
    Open
</button>

<dialog id="modal">
    <table>
        @foreach ($post->likers as $user)
            <tr>

                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('profile', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">
                        <img class="rounded-md" style="width:50px; height:50px;" 
                        src="{{ $user->profile_photo_url }}" alt="{{ $user->name }}" />
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="{{ route('profile', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">
                        {{$user->name}}
                    </a>
                </td> 
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table> 
    <button id="btn-close-modal" class="btn">
        Close
    </button>
</dialog>

<script>
  const btnOpenModal = document.querySelector("#btn-open-modal");
  const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector("#btn-close-modal");
  const modal = document.querySelector("#modal");

  btnOpenModal.addEventListener("click",()=>{
      modal.showModal();
  })

  btnCloseModal.addEventListener("click",()=>{
      modal.close();
  })

</script>
```

My js is very bad I would appreciate any help. Thanks